# ASP.net Linq to SQL grouping and adding at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table of products

products:

```
ProdID  | ProdName
     1  | shirt
     2  | pants
```

table of sizes:

```
SizeID | Size
     1 | small
     2 | med
     3 | large
```

Table of orders

```
OrderID   | ProdID    |  SizeID    | Qty
 1        |    1      |   1        |  4
 2        |    1      |   1        |  3
 3        |    1      |   2        |  2
 4        |    2      |   1        |  1
 5        |    2      |   3        |  1
```

How do I get results like this:

```
ProdName | Size    | Total qty ordered   (group by product and size add all quantities)
   shirt | small   |   7
   shirt | med     |   2
   pants | small   |   1
   pants | large   |   1
```

Thank you

Comment: nice concise question... well done +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from o in dc.Orders
group o by new { o.Product.ProdName, o.Size.Size } into g
select new { g.Key.ProdName, g.Key.Size, Total = g.Sum(or => or.Qty))};
```